# thread 'main' has overflowed its stack in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn Rust (I come from Java) and I'm having some problems.
I'm building a simple program that is the base for a connection pool.
When I run it, I get the runtime error `thread 'main' has overflowed its stack` and I cannot understand why.

here is main.rs

```
use hello_rust::concurrent_bag;
use hello_rust::concurrent_bag::BagEntry;

fn main() {
    let my_bagentry = BagEntry::new(String::from("ciao"));
    //println!("{}", my_bagentry.value());
    let mut contVec : Vec<BagEntry<String>>=vec![];
    contVec.push(my_bagentry);
    println!("state ={}", contVec[0]);
    println!("state ={}", contVec[0].value());
    let mut my_bag: concurrent_bag::ConcurrentBag<String> =concurrent_bag::ConcurrentBag::new();
    my_bag.addEntry(String::from("ciao Entry"));
    let result = my_bag.borrowEntry();
    if result.is_some() {
    println!("{}", result.unwrap().value());
    }
}
```

and here is lib.rs

```
pub mod concurrent_bag {
    use crate::concurrent_bag::BagEntryState::UNUSED;

    pub enum BagEntryState {
        UNUSED, USED, REMOVED
    }

    impl fmt::Display for BagEntryState {
        fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
            match *self {
                BagEntryState::UNUSED => write!(f, "UNUSED"),
                BagEntryState::USED => write!(f, "USED"),
                BagEntryState::REMOVED => write!(f, "REMOVED"),
            }
        }
    }

    impl PartialEq for BagEntryState {
        fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
            self == other
        }
    }

    pub struct BagEntry< T: std::cmp::PartialEq + fmt::Display> {
        state : BagEntryState,
        value: T,
    }

    impl<'a, T: std::cmp::PartialEq + fmt::Display> BagEntry<T> {
        pub fn new(value: T) -> BagEntry< T> {
            BagEntry {
                value,
                state: UNUSED,
            }
        }

        pub fn value(&self)->&T {
            &self.value
        }
        pub fn state(&self)->&BagEntryState {
            &self.state
        }
    }

    impl<'a, T: std::cmp::PartialEq + fmt::Display> PartialEq for BagEntry<T> {
        fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
            self.value == other.value
        }
    }

    impl<T: std::cmp::PartialEq + fmt::Display> fmt::Display for BagEntry<T> {
        fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
            write!(f, "{}", self.value)
        }
    }

    use std::sync::Arc;
    use core::fmt;

    pub struct ConcurrentBag<T: std::cmp::PartialEq + fmt::Display> {
        entry_list:Vec<BagEntry<T>>,
    }

    impl<'a, T:  std::cmp::PartialEq + fmt::Display> ConcurrentBag<T> {
        pub fn new() -> ConcurrentBag<T> {
            ConcurrentBag {
                entry_list: vec![],
            }
        }

        pub fn borrowEntry(&self) -> Option<BagEntry<T>> {
            println!("borrow vc size {}", self.entry_list.len());
            println!("value ={}", (self).entry_list[0].value());
            println!("state ={}", (self).entry_list[0].state());
            if (self).entry_list[0].state()==&UNUSED {

            }
            let result:Option<BagEntry<T>> =None;
            result
        }

        pub fn addEntry(&mut self, value: T) {
            let my_bagentry = BagEntry::new(value);
            (*self).entry_list.push(my_bagentry);
            println!("addEntry vc size {}", self.entry_list.len())
        }

        pub fn removeEntry(&mut self, value: T) {
            let my_bagentry = BagEntry::new(value);
            let index =(*self).entry_list.iter().position(|x| *x == my_bagentry).unwrap();
            self.entry_list.remove(index);
        }
    }
}
```

The problematic line is

```
if (self).entry_list[0].state()==&UNUSED
```

and I can't undestrand why since the line

```
println!("state ={}", (self).entry_list[0].state());
```

seems to work well.
Another issue that puzzles me is that if I use `&self` in borrowEntry I should use `*self` for getting access to `entry_list` but the program compiles and runs without errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't this code repeat itself forever?

```rust
impl PartialEq for BagEntryState {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self == other
    }
}
```

We implement `PartialEq` to make it possible to compare instances of a type with `==` and `!=` operators. So, it doesn't make sense to use `self == other` in there.

You can just derive `PartialEq`.

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub enum BagEntryState {
    UNUSED,
    USED,
    REMOVED,
}
```

Or, if you want to implement it by hand, you can do something like this.

```rust
impl PartialEq for BagEntryState {
    fn eq(&self, other: &BagEntryState) -> bool {
        match (self, other) {
            (&BagEntryState::UNUSED, &BagEntryState::UNUSED)
            | (&BagEntryState::USED, &BagEntryState::USED)
            | (&BagEntryState::REMOVED, &BagEntryState::REMOVED) => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, I was thinking that the two == (the one in the borrowEntry and the in in PartialEq) were different.